# Getting the version number of an application from within a library

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, assemblies, version

I'm developing a library that tries to get the version number of the application that uses it.

In my test application, when the lib is reading the version number using :

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
```

I'm getting the version number of the lib, not the main project.

Is there a simple way to find the version number of the main application, and not the one of my library ?

Thanks.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224032/getting-main-assembly-version-number

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Application.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.current%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to access the application instance that started the application:

```
Application.Current.GetType().FullName
```

Having said that, I don't think have the version number that applies to the application as a whole. For that you'll need to open the [`WMAppManifest.xml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769509%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) file and read the version from that. You can get access to the manifest file using:

```
var manifestUri = new Uri("WMAppManifest.xml", UriKind.Relative);
Stream manifestStream = Application.GetResourceStream(manifestUri);
```

Comment: Application.Current.GetType().Assembly.FullName works like a charm :) Thanks.

Comment: Application.Current.GetType().Assembly.FullName actually is not working in wp8

Answer (score 8):

To get the version number (1.2.0.0) , use the following code:

```
string version = XDocument.Load("WMAppManifest.xml").Root.Element("App").Attribute("Version").Value;
```

Comment: Works nicely for getting the value from WMAppManifest.xml. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssemlby().FullName;
```

assuming that this is supported on WP7. If not, try:

```
typeof(sometype).Assembly.FullName;
```

on one of types from your main module.

Comment: Thanks. But I won't be able to know a type from the main application in production. So this method is not suffisant. And GetEntryAssembly() does not work on Windows Phone 7, unfortunately.